# using Gerrit and Jenkins, remote branch merged changes, does not get updated anymore

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

I have a Jenkins job that builds from a specific branch. To test any changes, I would push to this branch and then trigger the Jenkins job. However, this branch merged changes for some reason and now, whenever the Jenkins job triggers, it will only build the branch using the merged changes - if I was to change the file in anyway, the job ignores these changes and will use the previously merged changes.

Additionally, whenver I push to this branch, running git status always shows this:

```
On branch branch_name
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch_name' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I don't want to do git push by itself as I'm sure this just performs a merge (I use git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch_name)

Comment: is the git status on your local repo or on the repo in jenkins workspace?

Comment: `refs/for/` implies that you're using Gerrit. Gerrit does its own special thing behind the scenes: you literally don't control what revision gets tested; instead, Gerrit controls this. You'll need to look at what Gerrit is doing when Gerrit invokes Jenkins. Git isn't responsible here; Gerrit is. (There's a normal usage pattern, and it sounds like something has gone wrong. As I don't actually *use* Gerrit I can't say anything further usefully, but I updated your tags.)

Answer (score 1):

`origin/branch_name` is actually `refs/remotes/origin/branch_name`. The `refs/for/branch_name` that you are pushing to is not recorded locally, in particular, it does not update `refs/remotes/origin/branch_name`. Therefore, `git status` always compares your local `branch_name` to a possibly outdated `origin/branch_name`.

Comment: to update the remotes' branches one should be able to run `git remote update origin`

Comment: @criztovyl That does not help in this case, because that would only download origin's `refs/heads` hierarchy, but OP did not update it; they updated the `refs/for` hierarchy and left `refs/heads` hierarchy in the old state that is behind the local branch.

Comment: Ah, I interpreted `refs/for/branch` as placeholder for `refs/heads/actual-branch-name`.